# How to set property in parent class and use it in child class?

Tags: php, oop

I would expect the following code to write "bar", but `getFoo` returns `NULL`.

What is the problem with that code, and how can i fix this?

```php
<?php

class A {
    protected $foo;

    public function getFoo() {return $this->foo;}
    public function setFoo($foo) {$this->foo = $foo;}
}

class B extends A{}

$a = new A();
$a->setFoo("bar");

$b = new B();

echo $b->getFoo();
```

Comment: OOP concept fails here. The object $a sets the variable $foo='bar' but the object $b hasn't set the variable $foo yet. So it returns null.

Whereas $a->getFoo() would return "bar" not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not really sure what you are doing, and i am quite sure you should read up on exactly how inheritance and objects work. You are specifying 2 classes witch is a template to build an object from. You the instanciate 2 objects $a and $b but these two objects do not share data.

You could use a static variable to do what you want but im not really sure what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?php

class A {
    protected static $foo;

    public function getFoo() {return self::$foo;}
    public function setFoo($foo) {self::$foo = $foo;}
}

class B extends A{}

$a = new A();
$a->setFoo("bar");

$b = new B();

echo $b->getFoo();
```

Outputs: "bar"

Comment: Right. I guess i have to change my logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is wrong. `$a` and `$b` are different instances. You set `$foo` in one instance, then create another that does not know about the first one.